# How to solve apt error "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages"

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-16.04, apt, aptitude

I am running this command:

```
sudo apt install libqt5svg5-private-dev
```

I receive the error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt5svg5-private-dev : Depends: libqt5svg5-dev (= 5.2.1-1) but 5.5.1-2build1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do to resolve this problem? I have run `apt install -f` to no avail and also tried `aptitude`.

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get update` before that `apt install -f` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pixelbook installing r-base dependency with held broken packages error](https://superuser.com/questions/1422059/pixelbook-installing-r-base-dependency-with-held-broken-packages-error)